# Laravel query builder- select the Laravel way from the Database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am getting a user query from a select button and saving it in the variable $selection. I would now like to return all row entries where $selection is equal to an exitant column description and where the corresponding row has a value higher than 0.

How do i do that the laravel way?

I have
$selection= (user selected apples)

Now I would like to return all rows where apples>0, sort by descending order.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using raw SQL, Eloquent, or the Query Builder?

Comment: It doesn't matter, I just need a working solution!

Comment: If I do: $lookingFor = Input::get('selection'); if ('selection'=='apples'){
   $lookingFor = DB::table('users')->select('apples');
   $selectedC=$lookingFor->addSelect('c')->orderBy('c', 'desc')->where('c', '>', 0)->get();
  } Would that be correct? How can I change it to adjust for pears, grapes etc. columns? Can I do a foreach loop? Or string compare?

Answer (score 0):

Hi first I want to say that I'm still a beginner in Laravel so my solution may not work. But I still wanna try to help you. I think I'm close:

```
$query = DB::table('users')->select('apples');

$users = $query->addSelect('apples')->orderBy('apples', 'desc')->where('apples', '>', 0)->get();
```

Comment: The key problem is that $selection can have the values of either apples, pears or bananas (columns of the table). (its a dropdown) How do I account for that? If for instance pears is selected, it shall only show the rows where pears >0.